# Trying to do a simple expression in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to calculate the average price of an order. I have the following simple expression:

```
=( Max(Fields!Price, "Totals") - Max(Fields!Discount_Value.Value, "Totals") + Max(Fields!Tax_Value.Value, "Totals") + Max(Fields!Freight_Charges.Value, "Totals") - Max(Fields!Total_Freight_Cost.Value, "ShipCodesShipped") / Max(Fields!Total_Orders_Count.Value, "Totals"))
```

It does not seem to work at all and just shows up as #Error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are any fields NULL? Not your error, but your last closing parenthesis should be moved to **before** the `/` division. Otherwise only Freight Cost is being divided by the Count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your expression

```
=( Max(Fields!Price, "Totals") ...
```

should be

```
=(Max(Fields!Price.Value, "Totals") ...
```